# Ionic2: Can't use NavController in a Service.

Tags: angular, service, ionic2, undefined

I'm still a learner. Not only in Ionic but in Angular too.

I've written some pages and wanted to add a footer to every page where the user can switch through all the main pages. After writing the 2nd page I saw that it would be nice to have a service for this because I used the same methods again.

Here is what my service looks like right now:

```
export class Navigation {
  public navCtrl: NavController;

  onLoadHome(){
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
  }   
}
```

When I now call the Navigator.onLoadHome() in an HTML-Template I got the following error: 
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

So I know my app finds the service and also finds the method. But my navCtrl is undefined. I tried another way by doing the following:

```
export class Navigation {
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController){}

  onLoadHome(){
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
  }
}
```

Now I get another error message: Can't resolve all parameters for Navigation.

I really don't know what to do to make this work. I hope you can help me.

(btw. I've shortened the class a bit. But the other methods do the same like onLoadHome, only for other pages.)

Comment: post the `NavController`

Comment: [`NavController`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) is only supposed to be injected in page/component. It is generally not a good idea to manipulate navigation stack in a service

Comment: You can pass `NavController` object to `onLoadHome()` function like this  `onLoadHome(navCtrl: NavController)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good way to navigate between pages but I hope this might help you

In the page you want to use the Service, you gotta import the Service then set it up like this

```
public mNavigation: Navigation;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
   this.mNavigation = new Navigation(navCtrl)
}
```

when you want to navigate, just call `this.mNavigation.onLoadHome();`

---

a better way is that you should use the `Nav` of `App` instead of `NavCtrl` in your Service. It looks like this

```
import { App } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class NavigationProvider {

  constructor(public app: App) {
  }

  onLoadHome(){
    this.app.getActiveNav().push(HomePage);
  }
}
```

then your page will be like this

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public mNavigationProvider: NavigationProvider,
    public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  onNavigate() {    
    this.mNavigationProvider.onLoadHome();
  }
```

Comment: I tried this one but I still get a runtime error: 'Can't resolve all parameters for Navigation'. By the way why it isn't a good way to navigate between pages?

Comment: "It's bad practice to change a view from a service (broken MVC). However, you could send events from services to the main controller, and the controller can use NavController (best way), or you could send NavController to your service like an attribute (not bad way...). Or you may need to create a component instead of using the service."
I just added another way, you should try

Comment: First of all your 2nd example worked perfectly! Thanks for this. :)

To your advice. This means I should write a navigation component. In this one, I should write down all methods and then I can use this component as a new footer for every page. Did I understand you correctly?